# main-domain of wordpress keep redirecting to subdomain

Tags: htaccess, wp-redirect

I was in process of deploying my wordpress website `mysite.com/NewSite` to `mysite.com` during the deployment I messed up something and my main site has started redirecting from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/NewSite`.

I have deleted everything from root folder, checked cpanel redirects section etc but everything looks fine. I also created `.htaccess` file under public_html folder but still no luck.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I know this more kind of a descriptive question. This is kind of super urgent as site is down which an issue. You help is required.

Comment: @fuxia I have checked wp-options and everything looks good there... when I install a fresh copy of wordpress... `mysite.com/wp-admin` is accessible and all of its settings but as soon as I hit `mysite.com` it redirects to `mysite.com/NewSite`

Comment: What is the significance of "NewSite"? Is it the actual directory where WP is installed? Was it only used in development? Was it only used on the development server? You use "subdomain" in the title, however, `example.com/NewSite` is a subdirectory, not a subdomain? What response do you get from `example.com/NewSite`? Have you confirmed this is an external 3xx redirect? What status code are you seeing: 301, 302, 3xx? Or do you get a 200 response (which indicates a client-side redirect)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Codex instructions:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

If you add these defines to your wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

These will override the options saved in your `wp_options` table, you should then remove the /NewSite suffix from your General Settings page. (Or if wp-admin is accessible now you may be able to just do that already.)

Alternatively you could edit the database directly and change the `home` and `siteurl` values in `wp_options` and that will achieve the same thing.

Comment: Updated but still the same issue :(:(

Comment: hmmm not sure, that should do it, try going to Permalinks page and clicking save, also logout and login again, could be browser caching now also, Google clearing cached redirects for your browser, and/or force refresh the page...

Answer (score 0):

I've never liked changing the domain name within the wp-settings.php file. I always change it directly in the wp-options table (in two places)...since that is where it will be defined (and read from in Settings). My theory is why not change it in the original spot (the wp-options table) rather than adjusting the values in the wp-settings file.

So, my first thing would be to remove those values from wp-config.php, then make sure the proper URL is in the wp-options table. And then to use a standard htaccess file according to the codex. Make sure you supply the full URL, with the protocol (as in https://www.example.com ).

Changing the permanlinks value will sometimes rewrite the htaccess file, but I always just use the standard htaccess from the Codex.